# Can you seek to a filehandle owned by another process as root?

Tags: proc, file-descriptors

There is a method to seek with a filehandle in C,

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

There is also a file in `fdinfo` for each file descriptor,

```
cat /proc/self/fdinfo/2
pos:    0
flags:  0100002
mnt_id: 24
```

What I want to do is call `fseek` on a file handle belonging to another process. Is this currently possible?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: @Kusalananda https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419537/3285

Comment: @Kusalananda did try it, I assume I tried it right but that it's impossible you be the judge. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing "no", but feel to correct me.

Here I create a test file (`/tmp/f`), and a perl script that echos its pid, opens our test file and sleeps.

```
echo foobar > /tmp/f;
perl -E'$|=1; print $$; open my $fh, "<", "/tmp/f" or die $!; sleep while 1'
```

The pid outputted was `19992`. Now here is what's going on in `/proc/19992/fd`,

```
$ cd /proc/19992/fd/
$ sudo cat 3
foobar
```

And in `/proc/19992/fdinfo`,

```
$ cat 3 
pos:    0
flags:  02100000
mnt_id: 27

$ sudo cat 3  > 3
bash: 3: Permission denied

$ sudo echo "pos=0"  > 3
bash: 3: Permission denied
```